# PyCharm Conda pip управление пакетами

Tags: python, pycharm, pip, conda

Имеем:

1. `Win 10`
2. latest `Miniconda` (с `Ananaconda` аналогичная ситуация)
3. `PyCharm 2016.2.1` (проблема была и на 5.0)

Проблема в том, что через встроенный в `pycharm` менеджер пакетов, используя `conda`, пропадает возможность установки пакетов и их обновления. Однако, установленные пакеты отображаются исправно. Весь функционал `pip` и `conda` исправно работает из-под консоли. Используя стандартный интерпретатор проблем с установкой пакетов нет. Позарез нужна `conda` в 'PyCharm'.

[image: Список доступных пакетов pip]

Comment: смотрите в сторону виртуального окружения, вроде как anaconda создаёт своё, отсюда могут быть несостыковки

Comment: По-умолчанию, conda - такой же интерпретатор, как и базовый. Пробовал создавать виртуальные окружения средствами conda - та же самая беда: установка и обновление из PyCharm не работает.

Comment: может быть у вас несколько версий Python установлено? не?

Comment: Всяко игрался с интерпретаторами - значения не имеет, тем более, что PyCharm работает напрямую с указанным ему интерпретатором

Answer (score 1):

Гугление по вопросу на протяжении двух дней ничего внятного не дало, однако, нашел схожие тикеты на багтрекекере JetBrains которые, вроде как, должны были пофиксить в 5.0.2 (к сожалению, репутатация на площадке stackoverflow не позволяет больше одной ссылки прикреплять, потому этим тикеты будут опущены), в связи с чем завел [новый тикет](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20477), будем следить за ним